# Can I use cloud-init to install and configure chef, but not actually run it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-cloudformation, cloud-init

I have a working CloudFormation template, with user data and cloud-init, connecting and building successfully to a hosted Chef server. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on an AWS EC2 stock image.

For my own purposes I would like to continue to do this, but

1) ***Not*** configure Chef to run as a service, only run on demand ("sudo chef-client")

...alternatively, or to complement this

2) perform the entire Chef install/config as before, but **only run once**, not as a service

I couldn't find the appropriate hooks, if any to achieve this wading through cloud-init examples. I wondered if there was some setting for Chef to allow for this use case? I tried using update-rc.d to disable chef-client but this didn't work due to it already being running.

Here is the fragment of the userdata in the CF template associated with the EC2 instance:

```
#cloud-config

resize_rootfs: true
apt_update: true
byobu_by_default: disable
manage_etc_hosts: false
disable_root: true
timezone: Europe/London
package_upgrade: true
package_reboot_if_required: true

apt_sources:
  - source: "deb http://apt.opscode.com/ $RELEASE-0.10 main"
    key: |
      -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
      Version: GnuPG v1.4.9 (GNU/Linux)
      xxxx truncated xxxxx
      -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

chef:
  install_type: packages
  server_url: xxxxxx
  node_name: xxxxx
  validation_name: xxxxxx
  validation_key: |
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    xxxx truncated xxxxx
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  run_list:
    - role[my-server]
  environment: production

output: {all: '| tee -a /var/log/cloud-init-output.log'}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this in `cloud-init` is to write a user data script that does the chef installation, configuration, and client run (these scripts are run by root as default, so you don't need to `sudo`).

`cloud-init` inputs are distinguished by their MIME types, which are in turn inferred by their first lines. As the [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) show, what you have there is a `text/cloud-config` part. You'll also want a "User-Data Script", which is simply a part that begins with a shebang, `#!`, or has a particular MIME Content-Type. With that in mind, your process is this:

1. Write a script that'll handle the chef installation and `chef-client` run. It can be `bash` or `sh` or any executable scripting language.
2. Take your existing cloud-config script, and strip the chef parts out of it.
3. Use the [`write-mime-multipart`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/cloud-utils/saucy/view/head:/bin/write-mime-multipart) script referenced in the [cloud-init docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) to wire your cloud-config part and user-script part together into one multipart MIME payload.
4. Drop that whole MIME message into your cloud formation template, which I assume is what you're using based on the quotation marks in your code. cloud-init (and, technically, cfn-init, the CloudFormation processor AWS wrote) will take care of the rest.

It's easy after you've done it once. Follow the multipart example in the docs and you'll see what's going on quickly.

Answer (score 1):

According to source code (but not to documentation!), chef-client would run only if "*install_type: gems*". And you can't control this until v.0.7.7.

For those who actually want to run, in cloud-init 0.7.7 option 'exec: true' added, which is set to true for "*install_type: gems*" and false for others.

Comment: I am getting `Jul  8 07:46:47 ubuntu [CLOUDINIT] cc_chef.py[DEBUG]: Skipping unknown chef template key 'exec'` with `exec: true` in my chef cloud init YAML running 0.7.7 on Ubuntu Xenial. :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io) both to install and configure Chef but not actually run it at all, and also to perform the entire Chef install/config as before, but only run once, not as a daemonized process.

1. According to the cloud-init Chef module [documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#chef), you can use the `exec` config key to control whether or not to run chef at all:

> exec: boolean to run or not run chef (defaults to false, unless a gem installed is requested where this will then default to true)

Example:

```
chef:
  # [other options]
  exec: false
```

2. According to the [source code](https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-init/tree/cloudinit/config/cc_chef.py), the [default arguments](https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-init/tree/cloudinit/config/cc_chef.py#n137) passed to [`chef-client`](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#options) are `['-d', '-i', '1800', '-s', '20']`, which run chef-client as a daemon with an interval of 1800 seconds and a 'splay' of 20 seconds. To run only once, you can use the [undocumented `exec_arguments`](https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-init/tree/cloudinit/config/cc_chef.py#n266) config key to specify an empty set of exec arguments, which will cause chef-client to run only once then exit, without being daemonized as a recurring background process.

Example:

```
chef:
  # [other options]
  exec_arguments: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install/configure chef-client and run it once from cfn-init which will be executed in cloud-init as below.Please refere aws docs for cloudfromation template and invoking [cfn-init](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) metadata.

Step 1 : copy chef-client installer to node using files section  in meta-data.

```
"files" : {
"c:/chef-client-12.04.exe" : {
"sorce" : "https://s3:link to file "
},
"client.rb" :{
"content":"..."}
"validation.pem":{..}
}
```

Step 2 : Add code to execute installer to install chef in cloud formation.

```
"commands": {
"1-install-chef": { 
"command":"msiexec /qn /i d:\\yourFolder\\chef-client-12.04.exe     ADDLOCAL=\"ChefClientFeature,ChefServiceFeature\"",
"waitAfterCompletion" :"1"
 }
 }
```

Step 3 : Run chef client once from cloud-init

```
"commands": {
"run-chef-client": { 
"command":"chef-client >c:\cheflogfile.log",
"waitAfterCompletion" :"1"
 }
 }
```

Note here: if you don't want to configure chef-client as service remove ADDLOCAL=\"ChefClientFeature,ChefServiceFeature\" from installation part.

Refer cfn-init link for exact json syntax.